# A single word meaning “absolute control over something”

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a single word meaning “absolute control over something”. For example, the government having absolute control over money. →

> The government has [a] ________ over money.

I thought of “stranglehold”, but I'd prefer something without the mild negative connotation. Even “monopoly” tends to give a slightly different meaning.

Any suggestions?

Comment: an exclusive control?

Comment: Yea... I'd be nice to get a simple Anglo-Saxon word, if there exists one...

Comment: "they have all control over money."? Old English all, eall, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch al and German all. :P

Comment: Another word that comes to my mind: 'sole control': adjective late Middle English (also in the senses ‘secluded’ and ‘unrivalled’): from Old French soule, from Latin sola, feminine of solus ‘alone’. Also, 'clannish'? But that seems to have a negative connotation too.

Comment: entire, full, whole, complete, total,

Comment: Milder than stranglehold (or monopoly) : "takeover" (or "dominance").

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question with "absolute control"? (Could go with some thing like exclusive as said above, too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you reconsider [***stranglehold***](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/mainmise), which actually is nowhere near as mild as you think.

> stranglehold
>
> 1. A grip around the neck of another person that can kill by asphyxiation if held for long enough.
> 2. Complete or overwhelming control: *in France, supermarkets have less of a stranglehold on food supplies* [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stranglehold)

If you're still not happy with it, consider:

***chokehold***

> 1:  a hold that involves strong choking pressure applied to the neck of another
>
> 2:  absolute dominance or control : *had a chokehold on the city's finances* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/choke%20hold)

***throttlehold***

> A vicious, strangling, or stultifying control [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throttlehold)

Answer (score 3):

Plenary.

It means unqualified or absolute control.

Comment: I believe this answer is worth considering. The definition of Oxford Dictionary says: ***without any limit; complete***. And here is an example: *The President does not have plenary control over the conduct of foreign relations.*

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following set of words:

- supremacy
- authoritarian
- totalitarian

**[supremacy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/supremacy)** (noun)

> supreme authority or power.

**[authoritarian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/authoritarian)** (adj.)

> of or relating to a governmental or political system, principle, or practice in which individual freedom is held as completely subordinate to the power or authority of the state, centered either in one person or a small group that is not constitutionally accountable to the people.

**[totalitarian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/totalitarian?s=t)** (adj.)

> of or relating to a centralized government that does not tolerate parties of differing opinion and that exercises dictatorial control over many aspects of life.

[References - Dictionary.com]

**Note** that authoritarian and totalitarian are synonymous with neutral to negative connotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I came across another one; 'absolutist' . But is there a simple Anglo-Saxon word for the same?

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for accepting the answer! Absolutism and Totalitarianism are synonymous. Every word is either simple or complex, and it depends on *how* you use it. Personally, I like **supremacy** for the given context (without a negative connotation). For instance, *the Government  established their supremacy on all financial aspects of the State.* Hope this helps.

Comment: None of your suggestions can cover the OP's context, **having absolute control over money**, better than monopoly, exclusive control, or sole control. Particularly, authoritarian and totalitarian are more related with a type (form) of government or dictatorship.

Comment: @Rathony Yes. *Monopoly* has been the standard term since Weber wrote of the state's "monopoly of legitimate physical force" (*das Monopol legitimen physischen Zwanges*) in *Politics as a Vocation* (1919).

Comment: Isn't *monopoly* largely associated with exclusive control of commodities of services by *businesses*? Like, for instance, Google is a monopoly in Search Engines and IKEA being a monopoly in D-I-Y furniture. Since the OP's context stated **Government** (controlling money), I gave these suggestions.

Comment: Many countries have monopoly over cigarette manufacturing and its sales, not to mention monopoly (exclusive/sole control) over money supply and its printing.

Comment: I believe in most countries, only the Government has *total*  control  over money supply and printing, and not some private entities. We should probably seek clarifications from OP as to why they are looking past monopoly/ sole control/ stranglehold.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy That's why you should not jump to answering a question. The question is not clear. I saw several cases where you answered without clarification being made by the OP. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295983/how-can-i-use-of-with-the-tools-in-hand/295995#295995) is another example. Your answer could depend on what the OP learned in what way.

Comment: Okay! Understood . Rookie mistake. And the same point is mentioned in [How to Answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)! Moving forward, will keep this in mind. Thanks
Edit: But my answer seems to have solved OP's problem. @Rathony. Does "accepting an answer" work differently? Sorry to digress, just curious

Comment: As I told you before, you will learn more as time goes by. Good luck and happy holidays! :-)

Comment: The OP's accepting your answer has no bearing on whether the answer is correct or it solved his problem or not. You are lucky that you didn't get any downvote. They are more merciful towards rookies I guess. If I had answered this way, my answer would have been bombarded with downvotes.

Comment: I would think that 'totalitarian' is perfectly suitable for describing my context. 'Government has a totalitarian control over the money supply'.

Comment: @user2277550 Take a look at this Oxford Online Dictionary [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/totalitarian). You need to use **total** before control. It's synonymous (not 100%) with undemocratic. It is related with a system of government.

Comment: @Rathony I'm for you and I cannot accept that this answer covers the OP's question but I want to know why you are so strict with some users.

Comment: @haha I am not strict with only some users at all. I am just trying to guide them (**hopefully**) in a nice way. :-) Happy holidays to you!

Answer (score 1):

***dominion***:

> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dominion):
>
>   Sovereignty or control.
>   *‘man’s attempt to establish dominion over nature’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dominion):
>
>   Control or the exercise of control; sovereignty: “The devil …
>     has their souls in his possession, and under his dominion” 
>     (Jonathan Edwards).
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dominion):
>
>   <sub>uncountable noun</sub>
>   **Dominion**
>   is control or authority.
>   *They truly believe they have dominion over us. [+ over]*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dominion):
>
>   [uncountable] formal control, or the right to rule over something
>   *At that time the island was under foreign dominion.*

Answer (score 0):

**To legislate**

> to mandate, establish, or regulate by or as if by legislation (Merriam Webster)

Implicit in legislating is the authoritative act of establishing of laws.

Comment: But, this doesn't mean total control, just control by laws

Answer (score 0):

**mastery**

> 2. Control or superiority over someone or something.
>      ‘*man's mastery over nature*’

[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mastery)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest either **sovereignty** or **carte blanche**, depending on whether the emphasis is more on complete control or on complete freedom to do anything with that something.

*sovereignty* : As [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sovereignty) defines it:

> Supreme power or authority.
>
> > ‘the sovereignty of Parliament’

*carte blanche* : As [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/carte-blanche.asp) defines it:

> Carte blanche is a figurative term to describe having free reign or flexibility with budget or spending decisions for a project or investment.

Answer (score -2):

autonomy

.
the right or condition of self-government.
"Tatarstan demanded greater autonomy within the Russian Federation"
2.
(in Kantian moral philosophy) the capacity of an agent to act in accordance with objective morality rather than under the influence of desires.